# Code to open file, run a macro, save the file and then run the next

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro "PrepareSheets_and_FillData" in this file: "C:\2013-2014\C1\C1 Macro.xlsm".

I need to run this macro on files labelled "1NB", "1SB", "2NB", "2SB" etc. Then I need to save the file as "1NB_Results", "1SB_Results" etc. So the code needs to open a file, run a macro from another location and then save the file based on the convention.

Is there any way to do this automatically?

This was the simple solution I used.

```
     Application.Workbooks.Open ("C\2013-2014\C1\1WB.xlsx")
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A2").Select
Application.Run "'C1 Macro.xlsm'!PrepareSheets_and_FillData"
Range("C16").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\2013-2014\C1\1WB Results.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close
```

And then repeat for each file.

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are very close. One thing you can do is put all the file names in an array, then just loop through each file in the array

```
file_names = Array("1NB", "1SB", "2NB", "2SB")

For Each indiv_file In file_names 
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("C\2013-2014\C1\" & indiv_file & ".xlsx")
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.Run "'C1 Macro.xlsm'!PrepareSheets_and_FillData"
    Range("C16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\2013-2014\C1\" & indiv_file & " Results.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close    

Next
```

Code is untested, there may be syntax errors

Answer (score -1):

How about a main macro and then `Call` the sub that does the magic and iterates over the files you need to process.